# How to custom sort two pandas dataframe column in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Apologies for a vague title; hopefully I can do a better job explaining. I have a `pandas` DataFrame `df` (sorted by `c1`):

```
c1       c2
A        A
A        D
A        E
B        C
B        D
C        E
C        G
D        C
D        F
E        A
E        D
E        F
F        C
F        E
F        G
G        A
G        B
G        D
G        G
```

How I want to sort `df` is sorting `c1` for a single value, then collect all corresponding `c2` values for such `c1` value and sort `c1` by those values next. In other words,

```
c1          c2
A           A
A           D (*)
A           E (**)
D (*)       C (***)
D           F (****)
E (**)      A
E           D
E           F
C (***)     E
C           G (*****)
F (****)    C
F           E
F           G
G (*****)   A
G           B (******)
G           D
G           G
B (******)  C
B           D
```

I used the *s for indicators. Here, you can see that `c1` is sorted by elements in the order of appearance in `c2`.

I first tried sorting both columns together,

```
df = df.sort_values(by = ["c1", "c2"])
```

or reindexing after sorting them differently,

```
df.reindex(pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values,1)).sort_values([0,1]).index)
```

and also have tried zipping them,

```
df['c1', 'c2'] = [list(x) for x in zip(*sorted(zip(df["c1"], df["c2"]), key=lambda pair: pair[0]))]
```

but none of the methods seem to deliver what I want. They simply deliver the identical-looking DataFrame to how `df` is initially sorted. Any insights on this custom sorting?

Comment: Can you explain more, why si `H` second group? Also is possible add input data coresspondint to output data after sort?

Comment: @jezrael done and done; I reduced the DataFrame and made it simpler. I basically want to sort `c1` by elements that earlier appear in `c2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ordered categoricals](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html) by unique values of `df2['c2']` column, so after [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by `c1` is sorting like you need :

```
df['c1'] = pd.CategoricalIndex(df['c1'], ordered=True, categories=df['c2'].unique())
df = df.sort_values(by = "c1")
print (df)
0   A  A
1   A  D
2   A  E
8   D  F
7   D  C
11  E  F
10  E  D
9   E  A
5   C  E
6   C  G
17  G  D
15  G  A
16  G  B
18  G  G
12  F  C
13  F  E
14  F  G
4   B  D
3   B  C
```

If possible some values from `c1` not exist in `c2` (like `F1` values in changed sample data) then solution is a bit different:

```
print (df)
    c1 c2
0    A  A
1    A  D
2    A  E
3    B  C
4    B  D
5    C  E
6    C  G
7    D  C
8    D  F
9    E  A
10   E  D
11   E  F
12   F  C
13  F1  E
14  F1  G
15   G  A
16   G  B
17   G  D
18   G  G
```

---

```
union = df[['c2','c1']].unstack().drop_duplicates()
print (union)
c2  0      A
    1      D
    2      E
    3      C
    6      G
    8      F
    16     B
c1  13    F1
dtype: object
```

---

```
df['c1'] = pd.CategoricalIndex(df['c1'], ordered=True, categories=union)
df = df.sort_values(by = "c1")
print (df)
    c1 c2
0    A  A
1    A  D
2    A  E
8    D  F
7    D  C
11   E  F
10   E  D
9    E  A
5    C  E
6    C  G
17   G  D
15   G  A
16   G  B
18   G  G
12   F  C
4    B  D
3    B  C
13  F1  E
14  F1  G
```